# How can I active a link when click, and deactivate the others in javascript?

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener, target, handle

I'm trying to handle just one element when I click in the link, but when I click on another it doesn't remove the active to other links. Can anyone help me ?
Here's my code . . .

```
let parentT = document.querySelector('.menu-item'); //PARENT
let allEl = parentT.querySelectorAll('a'); // ELEMENTS INSIDE PARENT

allEl.forEach(elem =>{   
  elem.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
      event.target.setAttribute('class', 'active');
      if(event.target.classList == "active") { 
         console.log(event.target);

      }
  }); 
});
```

I've try some methods but with no result.

Comment: In your click event, just loop over allEl and remove the active class. E.G, right after `preventDefault()`, `allEl.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));`

Comment: `event.target.classList == "active"` will give you incorrect results sometimes. Do `event.target.classList.contains("active")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted.
this code loops through all anchor elements when one is clicked and removes that active class from all of them, then adds the active class to the clicked element.

```js
let parentT = document.querySelector('.menu-item'); //PARENT
let allEl = parentT.querySelectorAll('a'); // ELEMENTS INSIDE PARENT

allEl.forEach(elem =>{   
  elem.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    allEl.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove('active');
    });
    event.target.classList.add('active');
  }); 
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>
```